# Where does chef-server store all the objects, such as nodes, clients, etc

Tags: chef-infra

The chef server must be storing the information about the various nodes, environments, etc in some files, presumably as json files. I am trying to find them so that I can create their backup, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most data, including all the you mentioned, is in the Postgres database. Cookbook metadata lives in Postgres but the actual file content lives in an S3-compatible service called Bookshelf. There is also the Solr index data which can technically be recreated from Postgres but depending on the number of nodes you have this might take longer than you prefer to wait on a restore.

Answer (score 0):

Chef provides documentation of [how to backup and restore](https://docs.getchef.com/server_backup_restore.html) a Chef Server.